# MS Access VBA: UBound & LBound functions returning subscript out of range error on class array

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am receiving a "Subscript out of range" error when calling the LBound() and UBound() functions on a global object's array in MS Access 2003 VBA.  I don't understand why this is occurring because I am certain the array has been initialized since I can access values from the array by referencing a known index of the array.

Here is my class that has a string array as a property.  I am initializing the array the Class_Initialize method.

```
Private pIgnoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForFields() As String

Public Property Get ignoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForFields() As String()
    ignoreDifferncesInDatabaseComparisonForFields = pIgnoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForFields
End Property

Public Property Get ignoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForField(index As Long) As String
    ignoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForField = pIgnoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForFields(index)
End Property

Public Property Let ignoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForField(index As Long, fld As String)
    If index > UBound(pIgnoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForFields) Then ReDim Preserve pIgnoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForFields(index)
    pIgnoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForFields(index) = fld
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    Dim ignoreDiffInDBComparisonForFields() As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' Add any new columns to skip inside this string
    ignoreDiffInDBComparisonForFields = Split("EligOvr,UpdateTS,groupStartDate,groupEndDate", ",")

    ReDim pIgnoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForFields(0)

    For i = LBound(ignoreDiffInDBComparisonForFields) To UBound(ignoreDiffInDBComparisonForFields)
        Me.ignoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForField(i) = ignoreDiffInDBComparisonForFields(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

I am declaring the object as a global variable at the top of my main module outside of any functions or subs.

```
Public settings As Options
```

Then, in my main function that I am calling,  I have the following line of code.

```
Set settings = New Options
```

Later on in my code, this function is called.

```
Function isAnIgnoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonField(field As String) As Boolean

    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim i As Long

    found = False

    x = settings.ignoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForField(1)

    For i = LBound(settings.ignoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForFields) To UBound(settings.ignoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForFields)
        If (LCase(field) = LCase(settings.ignoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForField(i))) Then
            found = True
        End If
    Next i

    isAnIgnoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonField = found

End Function
```

I get the error message in the for loop where I call the UBound and LBound functions the first time it hits the "For i ..." line.  It does not make it through any iterations of the loop.  I set x to the value at location 1 in the array as a test, and the value does populate without errors, so the array has been initialized.  Does anyone know why I am getting the "Subscript out of Range" error?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the line:

```
Public Property Get ignoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForFields() As String()
    ignoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForFields = pIgnoreDifferencesInDatabaseComparisonForFields
    ' ^ correct typo here ^
End Property
```

When I fixed this, your code compiled, and it ran properly without the `Subscript out of range` error.

Comment: Hint: if you use `Option Explicit` in your module declaration area, you can find errors such as this just by compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I have used VBA to much in Access, but I know its can do some interesting things in Excel. I would try setting the the upper bound to Ubound() -1 and see what happens. Sometimes VBA uses the standard convention of Starting at 0-9 other times its Starts at 1 depending on the object type.

Also as a side in the final for loop, you might want to consider adding an Exit For, if the match is found. No reason to complete the loop if its True.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Unfortunately the UBound() - 1 had no effect.  Even when I hover over the LBound() or the UBound() functions to see their values in break mode, they both show <Subscript out of Range>.  Also, I believe the UBound() - 1 would have only helped if it had been iterating through all of the values in the array and went one too far, but it is coming up with this error before it goes through the loop even once.

Comment: Can you confirm that ignoreDiffInDBComparisonForFields () is being populated properly?

Comment: Yes, that variable is populating correctly.  It turns out there was a typo in my getter that returned the entire array, found by @kismert.